# Associativity of infinite matrix product.

Tags: infinite-product, associativity, infinite-matrices, nonassociative-algebras

Many texts reads "It is well known that for infinite matrices multiplication is non-associative". A treatise on this can be found in [On the associativity of infinite matrix multiplication](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09779).

However, if $x$ and $v$ are infinite vectors, and $A$ is a semi-infinite matrix, then Does the product $x^\intercal A u$ is associative?, that is to ask whether the following equation holds?

$$(x^\intercal A) u = x^\intercal (A u)$$

I am interested in the particular case when $A$ is a lower-triangular semi-infinite matrix.

Comment: I don't know whether this is interesting for you. I have a nice example, when $V(x) \cdot (P \cdot S1)$ cannot be computed because the row-column-dotproducts in the right parenthese are infinite (the impossible matrixmultiplication $ P \color{\red}{\not *} S1$ is marked red here) , but $(V(x) \cdot P) \cdot S1 = V(x+1) \cdot S1 $ is possible (non-divergent for a range of values in $x$). Thus there is at least one non-associative example...